# JSON column for array of double

Tags: postgresql, analytics

I'm designing database for analytics application. My data is loaded from CSV file. This file contains a series of double values (maybe more than 100k values) for an object called 'feed'.

I want to store these arrays of double into JSON column in PostgreSQL and "partition" the data. I will pick an factor number (for example: 1000) it means that for each JSON, it contains maximum 1000 values. As a result, if you have 3000 values in CSV then you will have 3 rows, each row will contain a JSON of 1000 values like in the below:

```
Table feed
----------------------------------------
| id | data |
| 1  | { data: [1,2,3,4...1000]}
| 2  | { data: [1001,1002,...,2000]}
| 3  | { data: [2001,2002,...,3000]}
```

If you want to update any value then I will duplicate the array inside each JSON with new value and the others will be -1.

For example, if you want to change value 2002 (at index 1) to 4500, then the table will be:

```
Table feed
----------------------------------------
| id | data |
| 1  | { data: [1,2,3,4...1000]}
| 2  | { data: [1001,1002,...,2000]}
| 3  | { data: [2001,2002,...,3000], new_data: [-1,4500,-1,-1...]}
```

And maybe I will add some additional metadata columns to describe the JSON data such as array_length, is_modifed.... for easy to process.

I don;t know with this design I can easily to do CRUD operations? And it's good for render and update chart real time? Because the read, write, update... this array data is so frequently. Could any one give me some advice about this?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder how you could possibly have come up with such a contrived scheme. What's the point? Are there any reasons/requirements we don't know about that led you to this?

Comment: Most of the time the array is used to render the chart and when someone edit any point in the chart then that value will be updated and another thing is client will poll for new data change to refresh the chart. So I think using JSON for easy to read and render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSON data in the scenario that you describe is a very bad idea.

JSON [is a lightweight ***data-interchange*** format](http://www.json.org) and as such not particularly efficient as a ***data storage*** and ***data manipulation*** format and PostgreSQL as a ***relational data storage model*** is not particularly suitable either for JSON manipulation (JSON has a hierarchical data structure) or large arrays.

A few more specific reasons why your idea is not efficient:

- Putting 1,000 double values in an array yields a data structure of more than 8,000 bytes (assuming `jsonb` data type: 8,000 bytes for the doubles, some overhead for the structure itself and its descriptors; regular `json` would most likely even be bigger because every value will have at least 8 characters to accurately describe the magnitude of every value). This means that the table will be [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)ed, which incurs a performance penalty.
- Updating a single value in an array requires that the whole record (in the main table and in the TOAST table) be rewritten and that is extremely inefficient.

You are much better off using a simple relational structure inside PostgreSQL, with triggers to implement your logic. If your charting client expects a JSON document as input, then PostgreSQL can generate that on-the-fly. For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE feed (
    "index"    integer,
    value      double precision
);

CREATE FUNCTION trf_upd_feed RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    -- This DELETE statement throws out unwanted data (the -1 values in your example)
    -- Usually there will be very few rows (just 1?) that get deleted
    DELETE FROM feed
    WHERE ("index" - 1) / 1000 = (NEW."index" - 1) / 1000;  -- integer division!
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_feed_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON feed
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_upd_feed();
```

When you need the data for charting you can run a simple query to get the data for the slice of the values as a JSON object:

```
SELECT json_build_object('data', arr) AS json_data
FROM (
    SELECT json_agg(coalesce(feed.value, -1)) AS arr
    FROM generate_series(1001, 2000) i(x)
    LEFT JOIN feed ON feed."index" = i.x) sub;
```

This is overall much more efficient because you do not need TOAST tables and you do not store data that means nothing (all the -1 values).

**Alternative**

From your description I get the idea that your charting client maintains its own cache of values and then periodically polls for new data in the database. If that is the case, you should change your logic. Rather than changing values (deleting records) upon an update, you should do so when the charting app reads the data; for that you need a function instead of the update trigger (so delete that one if you have created it already):

```
CREATE FUNCTION chart_data (start_idx integer, end_idx integer) RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    json_data json;
BEGIN
    SELECT json_build_object('data', arr) INTO json_data
    FROM (
        SELECT json_agg(coalesce(feed.value, -1)) AS arr
        FROM generate_series(start_idx, end_idx) i(x)
        LEFT JOIN feed ON feed."index" = i.x) sub;

    -- Data has been read, so now it can be deleted
    DELETE FROM feed
    WHERE "index" BETWEEN start_idx AND end_idx;

    RETURN json_data;
END;
$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

And then simply call `SELECT chart_data (1001, 2000);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually we don't have a DBA and I don't know much about PostgreSQL and how far PG supports JSON. The idea is just one of suggestions in my team. When I should use JSON for storage?

Comment: PG has functions to manipulate JSON documents (especially useful for the binary `jsonb` data type), but in general you should let PG store the JSON and do the manipulation at the client side. PG can search (and index) simple JSON documents (i.e. well structured but not too hierarchically deep) but in general you want to disassemble complex structures into a relation model (one or more tables) and ingest and generate JSON documents as shown in the answer.